# Cloudflare > Digital Ocean Server > Nginx proxy flow not working

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean, nuxt.js, cloudflare

I'm working on a proyect made with Nuxtjs and with a complex (and really headaching) flow of redirections.

The variables are:

**Domain**: exampledomain.gob.ar

**Cloudflare IP (obviously an example)**: 123.45.67.89

**Digital Ocean Droplet IP (obviously another example)** 098.765.4.321

The flow starts at the cloudflare account on which DNS zone i have an A and a CNAME records with a subdomain pointing to the digital ocean droplet IP like this:

**Type**: A - **Name**: subdomain - **Content**: 098.765.4.321 - **TTL**: Auto - **Proxy Status**: Proxied

**Type**: CNAME - **Name**: www.subdomain - **Content**: subdomain.exampledomain.gob.ar - **TTL**: Auto - **Proxy Status**: Proxied

Then in the Digital Ocean droplet i have

[image]

and inside that droplet i have a proyect mounted on localhost:3000 and a file named **subdomain.exampledomain.gob.ar** following content inside the directories **/nginx/sites-available** and **/nginx/sites-enabled**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    index index.html;
    server_name subdomain.exampledomain.gob.ar www.subdomain.exampledomain.gob.ar;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

the nginx config is tested and okay, the project is mounted and running and everything has an SSL certificate correctly installed, but then i access **subdomain.exampledomain.gob.ar** i get:

[image]

and when i check on the network tab on the navigator debugging tools i see the request is being made at **123.45.67.89:80** (Port 80 of Cloudflare ip address)

I know this is probably messed up in some point, but i'm a beginner at this and i really don't know what am i doing wrong.

Comment: Assuming a restart/reload of `nginx` and nothing wrong when `nginx -t`

Comment: Yes, i reloaded nginx runngin systemctl restart nginx

Comment: Do you see anything about the 404 in the `nginx` logs

Comment: It was actually working, the browser just cached the error page from a previous wrong configuration.